# Allow two components to intercept swipe events in VerticalViewPager

Tags: android, view

I have VerticalViewPager where on vertical movement I change the pages of the view pager but inside the view pager I have a horizontal viewPager that is moving items inside from left to right.

Is there a way to setup the verticalView to consume the events that are for Y(swipe up/down) and let the viewPager inside handle the X events about (swipe left/right) ?

I saw some of the answers here but couldn't find a solution for me, that's why I am asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this (https://github.com/juliome10/DoubleViewPager) should help you.

This library has been built with horizontal view pager which has vertical view pager on each child. When the user triggers events on each child, they pass it to the parent. Then, if the event is vertical, the child processes it, otherwise, if the event is horizontal, the parent processes it.

Then, you can swipe in X and Y.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out :)

Comment: I managed to implement it inside my project but however I have one issue I cant figure out,its that when I try to slide vertical sometimes recognize it as horizontal slide even though I added a move offset over the x access. if I show my touch code inside the view will you be able to give me any hint If I do something wrong ?